# Execute sh command in Entrypoint

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I created a image from minio/mc and I want cat file inside my container to make something like this.

```
docker run -it --entrypoint='sh cat hello.txt' my/miniomc > hello.txt
```

How to write that this cat is an sh command to execute ?

In my situation I can't use `docker cp`

Thanks for your help

Comment: you also achieve this by `docker run -d my/miniomc cat hello.txt > hello.txt`. do you want to use entrypoiny only? cat is the command?

Answer (score -1):

The entrypoint parameter requires a binary file.

Try this :

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/cat my/miniomc hello.txt > hello.txt
```